# Scroll a 100% height div over top of main content area while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

What I'm trying to do is a little hard to explain. I want to have a "panel" that would be 100% of the window height and is overlaid on top of the main content of the website. What I want to happen is to have the main website content locked to the top of the browser window and have this "panel" over top of it. This part is easy just using z-index. The problem I'm having is getting the main content of the site to stay fixed at the top of the browser window and when the user scrolls down **only** the "panel" slides up to reveal the main part of the website below it. Once the panel has cleared the top of the browser window I want the main part of the site to scroll as usual. I would like this to be driven by jQuery.

Here's the HTML I have:

This is an overlay that needs to slide over top of the main content when the user scrolls down. 

This is the main content of the website.

And some CSS:

```
html, body {height:100%;}

.panel {height:100%; background-color: rgba(186,85,85,0.38); position: relative; z-index:1;}

.main {position: absolute; top:0px; min-height: 1500px;}
```

EDIT: Think of this effect like a curtain rising on a stage. The stage stays in place while the curtain rises.

Comment: A plugin like jarallax http://www.jarallax.com/demo/ should give you what you need, although it would take a little more adjustment to your layout.

You can set animations for each div at different points in the scrolling progress.

Comment: Can you show some demonstration? Its quite confusing and unclear

Comment: I updated my post. Think of it like a curtain rising on a stage.

Comment: They provide video tutorial that show a step by step in implementing the plugin: http://www.jarallax.com/?page=tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Viewing this problem from overly simple point of view, using `position: fixed` can fix the main content website while others scroll.

Comment: When I set `.main {position:fixed}` then it kills scrolling on the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Dustin,

Based on your mention of a scrolling curtain, I set up a 100% height div placed above a main content area so that scrolling the page brings the content into view. I was unsure about the fixed area you're looking for, so I just placed a fixed div at the top of the page. If you'd like that div to start to scroll once the "curtain" is all the way up, you might want to look into addclass based on a scroll position - unfortunately, you'll have to ask someone better-versed in Jquery for help on that.

**CSS**:

```
html, body
{
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
}

#curtain {
height: 100%;
width: 500px;
background-color: red;
display: block;
}

#content {
width: 500px;
background-color: blue;
}

#both {
height: 100%;
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#sticky_content {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
width: 200px;
background-color: green;
}
```

​
**HTML**:

```
<div id="both">
<div id="sticky_content">This Sticks</div>
<div id="curtain">Text?</div>
<div id="content">This is where the main page body content would go...</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/YHFrU/51/) I put together. The curtain is red, the content area is blue, and the sticky area is green to keep the distinctions clear.

-Marcatectura

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your efforts in helping me. I think I found a pretty good solution though. I found something that is conveniently named Curtain.js. https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js This plugin creates the exact same effect that I was looking for :)